# WP styling issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've made a theme for my new site and trying to upload it on my live site for testing and kind having an issue with the styling. I used a different stylesheet for my own theme which is in a different folder however that worked fine on localmachine, so I thought I'd try to import it in WP style.css but still the same.

this is how I link my css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/stylesheets/style.css" />
```

Local test:
[image]

Live one:
[image]

Comment: Have a link to the site?

Comment: http://www.markestrada.co.uk/ give me to seconds to deactivate the underconstruction plugin.

Comment: okay you can check it now.

Comment: I see the local layout so there is probably something with your cache.

Comment: Cool thanks.

It looks like you need to fix some URL's in either the theme, or the content.

A bunch of images are popping errors, trying to load from 127.0.0.1

www.markestrada.co.uk/:75 GET http://127.0.0.1/wp-portfolio/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/logo-250x250.png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Should have mentioned, if you have 127.0.0.1 links in the actual content, you should check out https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/. Otherwise, ensure you use wpurl('stylesheet_directory') or similar to point to the right url path in your theme.

Comment: Hm i don't see any 127.0.0.1 anywhere though, I'm pretty sure its pointing to the right path otherwise the rest of the style won't work though. I imported my own css to WP css @import url('stylesheets/style.css'); I'm using scss  so yeah.

Comment: @RichardDenton Will try to clear my cache on Chrome, I tried it on my other browsers and still the same.

Answer (score 0):

A Lot of things can be happened.
Try see in ur console in browser (f12 chrome or fox). 
[image: console]

if u get error:

[image: error]

Try browse source. But it can be just a cache trouble. Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> on ur page - this will be reload page without caching.
Also check images exists on ur server, try use absolute path.

Comment: try viewing your site on a different computer.

Comment: But those are just images which won't cause the menu bar style issue and I've just re-uploaded,